# Reference a JSON schema located in another directory?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a parent schema that reference to a child schema in another directory.

I have the parent schema:

```
 {
      "properties":{
        "description": {
          "type": "object",
          "after": {"type": "string"},
          "before": {"type": "string"}
        },
        "ranges": {
          "$ref": "Fields/Ranges.json"
        },
        "resets": {
          "$ref": "Fields/Resets.json"

        },
        "values": {
          "$ref": "Fields/Values.json"
        },
        "display": {
          "type": ["string", "null"]
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
```

And Child schema :

Fields/Ranges.json

```
{
  "id": "http://example.com/json/schema/aig_doc_schema/models/Fields/Ranges.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "type": "array",
    "start": {"type": "number"},
    "width": {"type": "number"},
  }
}
```

But when I try to validate it using json-spec, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/json", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonspec/cli.py", line 541, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonspec/cli.py", line 205, in __call__
    return self.run(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonspec/cli.py", line 484, in run
    validated = load(args.schema).validate(args.document)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonspec/validators/draft04.py", line 320, in validate
    obj = validator.validate_default_properties(obj, pointer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonspec/validators/draft04.py", line 374, in validate_default_properties
    if name not in obj and validator.has_default():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonspec/validators/bases.py", line 87, in has_default
    return self.validator.has_default()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonspec/validators/bases.py", line 83, in validator
    self._validator = self.context.resolve(self.pointer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonspec/validators/factorize.py", line 48, in resolve
    return self.factory(self.registry.resolve(pointer),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonspec/reference/bases.py", line 45, in resolve
    obj, fetcher = self.prototype(dp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonspec/reference/bases.py", line 93, in prototype
    obj = self[dp.document]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonspec/reference/bases.py", line 100, in __getitem__
    raise NotFound('{!r} not registered'.format(uri))
jsonspec.reference.exceptions.NotFound: u'http://example.com/json/schema/models/Fields/Ranges.json' not registered
```

I have tried other thing like adding the full path of the child schema and adding file:// But none of them works. HAs any one one got a work around this? 
Thanks for the time.

Comment: Which parser are you using? Which language?

Comment: They are python parsers. They can be run on a command- line. This is the command line I used. `json validate --schema-file=schema/models/Field.json --document-file=../json/field.json`